# How do i add record from data table

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I would add record to my table with a form to fill out, but there is a error from `ListerPF()`

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here is the whole process:

```
await App.methode.AddNewPF(Label_NumeroNF.Text, DatePicker_Date.Date, Editor_LibelleNF.Text, Picker_TypeFrais.SelectedItem.ToString(), double.Parse(Entry_Quantite.Text), double.Parse(Entry_Tarif.Text), double.Parse(Entry_Montant.Text), double.Parse(Entry_MontantTotal.Text), CheckBox_CCEntreprise.IsChecked,  int.Parse(Entry_Imputation.Text));
Navigation.PushAsync(new PostesNF());
```

And the code behind "AddNewPF" is:

```
public async Task AddNewPF(string numero , DateTime date, string libelle, string typeFrais, double quantite, double tarif, double montant, double montantTotal, bool carteCredit,   int imputationCC)
        {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                result = await connection.InsertAsync(new DB_PosteNF { Numero = numero, Date = date, Libelle = libelle, TypeFrais = typeFrais, Quantite = quantite, Tarif = tarif, Montant = montant,  MontantTotal = montantTotal, CarteCredit = carteCredit,   ImputationCC = imputationCC});
                StatutMessage = $"{result} poste de frais ajouté : {numero} | {typeFrais} ";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatutMessage = $"Impossible d'ajouter le poste de frais avec le numéro: {numero}. \nErreur : {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
```

When the "PosteNF" page appears, I have this code

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    CollectionViewPF.ItemsSource = await App.methode.ListerPF();
}
```

the problematic code "ListerPF" is:

```
public async Task<List<DB_PosteNF>> ListerPF(DB_ListeNF datareceived)
{
    try
    {
        string numero = datareceived.Numero;
        //return await connection.Table<DB_PosteNF>().ToListAsync();
        return await connection.Table<DB_PosteNF>().Where(x => x.Numero == numero).ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StatutMessage = $"Impossible d'afficher la liste des postes de frais. \nErreur : {ex.Message}";
    }
    return new List<DB_PosteNF>();
}
```

But when I go back to the "PostesNF" page, the registered data is not displayed. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Bonjour!Can you set a breakpoint at `connection.InsertAsync` and confirm you have inserted the record to the table?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFTThis is where the problem appears, it goes to catch with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I have also this "table ListePF has no column named Tarif"

Comment: I think this is the root cause of the issue, please make sure the you can create a right object corresponding to your model before inserting into your database.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I add a record to my table with `AddNewPF` and after i launch `InsertAsync (new DB_PosteNF {}`

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT i have do update to my text ! i have find where is the problem, is it at "ListerPF"

Comment: That's a good news!If you think my answer is helpful, please help it.Hope you have a good time!Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per your code snippets, the model is `DB_PosteNF`  with 10 properties.The key is that when you retrieve the records from the data table, I think you need a `ObservableCollection<DB_PosteNF>` to receive these entities that read from the database.Below is the code snippets for your reference:

**First**, define a UserCollection using `ObservableCollection`

```
public ObservableCollection<User> UserCollection { get; set; }
```

**Then**, in `OnAppearing` method:

```
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            UserDB db = await UserDB.Instance;
            List<User> a = await db.GetUserAsync();
            UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(a);
            userinfodata.ItemsSource = UserCollection;
        }
```

PS: In my case, the mode is `User`.